# Add a unique File ID to PDF documents received

Tags: python, node.js, windows, pdf, metadata

I need to track PDF documents RECEIVED.      I can keep a list of the documents in a database, however sometimes the documents get renamed or moved, so the file path to the PDF is not always reliable.
For other document types, I sometimes add a unique ID as metadata, so that I can recognize that a file that was moved and/or renamed is the same as one seen previously.
I am looking for a solution that will work on Windows 10, and would prefer a solution based on Node.js, although Python would also be acceptable.
The documents are received from many different sources, and I do not have the option of requiring the source of the document to add a unique identifier.
I have use IPTCinfo in this way for media files, but (as far as I know) that can't be used with PDFs.
I am looking for something similar that can be used with PDFs.

Comment: PDF files have an /ID key in the info dictionary. Either use the existing ID or generate the IDs yourself. Then that information is stored in the PDF file itself and preserved even if it gets modified, e.g. through a file-size optimizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `md5sum`:

```
import os 

def check_md5sum(file_path):
    md5sum = os.system(f'md5sum {file_path}')
    return md5sum
```